# My web cam zoom changes from app to app

Tags: windows, windows-10, webcam

I got a new webcam for these Covid times, and am having issues with the amount of zoom. Some apps zoom in so much so that my face takes up the entire screen, others you can see the whole room. I've searched for where to configure this in the apps (Skype, Zoom, Google meet) but none of them have this option, so it seems to be related to the OS or the camera itself, but it doesn't make sense cause it differs from app to app.

Any ideas where I can configure this? I'm using Windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

Different video resolutions use different aspect ratios: the "standard quality" 640×480 is 4:3, but "high definition" 1280×720 (and higher) are 16:9. Changing between aspect ratios causes parts of the image to be cropped, which will be perceived as zooming in.

In Zoom in particular, disabling HD will cause camera to stream 4:3 video, while enabling it switches to 16:9. Changing this setting should toggle the zoom (no pun intended) as a side effect.

Comment: Yeah that much I noticed, but I'm still seeing a huge difference even within the same resolution (between apps). It zooms in the whole thing, bot just one axis...

Comment: @tbkn23 If it's just one axis, then it's certainly adjustment to a fixed aspect ration. Apps are cropping left+right to make 16:9 video 4:3 or top+bottom to turn 4:3 into 16:9. The effect will differ depending on which resolution is selected and what's the intended aspect ratio for that particular app. You can't do anything about this, if one app insists on 16:9 and the other one on 4:3 the visible area will always be different because its shape is different.

Comment: Ah sorry, typo. was "not just one axis". And also I don't see the same issue with other people using the same apps... So I'm thinking it has to be my camera or configuration somehow. But I haven't been able to find anywhere to configure such settings.

Comment: Both axis can also be explained. Your camera's sensor is natively 16:9. When you're lowering resolution to 640x480 camera cuts off left+right to achieve 4:3. Then some software that operates on 4:3 cuts off top+bottom to make it 16:9 again. Anyway, the camera doesn't know what software it's streaming video for, so it's certainly caused by some setting.